# Ruby-Rails Running code and saving the output in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

My code reads in log files and parses the data. The output gets me something that looks like this:

```
name: jon
domain: jon@gmail.com
date: 2-12-2012
```

I have created my database called "databases" And I want to have my parsed data updated in the database without using simply CRUD actions. (I don't want to manually create each log) My question is how would I go about automatically taking the parsed data (after running my code) and having it save and show up in the database.

Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadJunaid Where would I place this code?

Comment: right after parsing the data

Comment: @muhammadjunaid sorry for not being clear, I meant to ask which file i place this in. Or if its in the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code right after the parsing code but you have to create a record first:

```
name: jon
domain: jon@gmail.com
date: 2-12-2012
model = Model.new
model.update_columns(name: name,domain: domain, date: date)
```